# First differences in the permutations leading to Eulerian numbers

Tags: permutations

Let $T(n, k)$ ([A008292](https://oeis.org/a008292)) be the number of permutations of length $n+1$ of distinct elements $p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_{n+1}$, where the elements belong to the set $\left\lbrace1, 2,\cdots, n+1\right\rbrace$, $p_1=1$, and for which
$$(k-1)(n+1) < \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} (p_{j+1}-p_j)\bmod (n+1) < k(n+1)$$
when $1 < k < n$ and $T(n,1)=T(n,n)=1$.

How can this be proved?

By the way,
$$T(n,k)=\left\langle\! n\atop k-1 \right\rangle\!$$

Comment: What exactly should be proved? The formula after "by the way"? It is equivalent to one of standard definitions of Euler numbers (via descents).

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you for commrent! Sorry, but I do not understand why is it so.

Comment: just substitute $(b-a) \bmod (n+1)=(b-a)+(n+1)\cdot \textbf{1}(a>b)$ for $b=p_{j+1}$, $a=p_j$